# Going back using a NavigationController crashes when accessing the same ViewController

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, push, back

Below is the hierarchy in question.

The "ViewController - MyConnection" in the top left is my main ViewController. I implement a NavigationController system. From the main VC a user can go to the "Choose Server VC" or the "Choose Test Type" VC using Push. Having done that a user can then press back and return to the main VC, no problem.

A user can also Push to the "Preferences" VC from the main VC. From the prefences VC a user can also go to the "Choose Server VC" or the "Choose Test Type" VC, again without issue.

However, when going back to the preferences VC **AND THEN** back to the Main VC the **app crashes**!

Using the debugger the viewWillAppear gets called in the Main VC but that's where if fails.

[image: Storyboard]

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. All the segues have unique names.

**The debugger doesn't offer a great amount of detail** about what is causing the crash. Any way to get more detail out of the debugger?

**EDITS:**

viewWillAppears in ViewController-MyConnection:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];    

}
```

In Preferences VC:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

There are no ViewWillAppear methods in the other two VCs

Comment: Please show the viewDidLoad/ViewDidAppear code of the 4 VCs above. Also have you considered changing your logic to use a UITabBarController?

Comment: I have updated the questions with the vDA code

Comment: I should point out that navigating back from Preferences to the main VC works, it's only when you go to Preferences and either Choose Server or Test Type and then back to the main VC that it fails

Comment: The debug error I get is EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0). (address is actually equal something else). I understand this is telling me something isn't in memory? Does this help narrow the issue down?